# An unknown data representation notation in drupal

Tags: drupal

```
s:17:"thumbnail";
s:1:"1";
a:0:{}
a:9:{s:5:"title";s:2:"-5";s:10:"body_field";s:1:"0";s:20:"revision_information";s:1:"3";s:6:"author";s:1:"2";s:7:"options";s:1:"4";s:4:"menu";s:2:"-1";s:4:"path";s:1:"5";s:12:"image_attach";s:2:"-4";s:13:"path_redirect";s:1:"6";}
```

What is the name of this notation? Who is responsible for its standardization?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the PHP function [serialize](http://www.php.net/serialize) called internally by [drupal_write_record](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/6) that is responsible for this notation.

---

Per line:

- the first part ("s" or "a" in your example) is the **type** ("s" is string, "a" is array)
- the second part is the **length** (however "thumbnail" is only 9 chars, I wonder why it says s:17, there are probably extra empty chars)
- the third part is the **value** as string (or as object if it's an array or an object)

Comment: If you are only using PHP, it is a de-facto standard because "serialize" is such a widely-used function. On the other hand, I never encountered this syntax anywhere else (though I have seen java classes that can read such PHP-serialized data), so I don't know why historically the PHP makers chose this syntax, it's not a famous standard like JSON as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

More specifically, the [serialize](http://php.net/serialize) function is actually called internally by Drupal using the schema API automatically. A field can be set as "serialized" and Drupal will internally handle the conversions of arrays and objects.